# Error Retrieving Array Value

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an array with the following values,

```
Array(
[new_count] => 1
[updated_count] => 0
[error_count] => 0
[error_indices] => Array
    (
    )

[unmodified_indices] => Array
    (
    )

[persisted_recipients] => Array
    (
        [0] => ZEBhcy5jb20=
    )

[errors] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

and I'm trying to pass to a variable only this value,

```
[persisted_recipients] => Array
    (
        [0] => ZEBhcy5jb20=
    )

$recipient_id = $array_retorno['persisted_recipients'][0];
```

but I'm getting the following error

Undefined offset: 0 [APP\Controller\PostsController.php, line 129]

what is wrong?

Comment: So `$array_retorno` is an array that contains multiple arrays? Sounds like you need `$array_retorno[5][0]`.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($array_retorno)` and post results in the question? I am not sure what is actually in the array.

Comment: return from var_dump                                                                      
array(7) { ["new_count"]=> int(1) ["updated_count"]=> int(0) ["error_count"]=> int(0) ["error_indices"]=> array(0) { } ["unmodified_indices"]=> array(0) { } ["persisted_recipients"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "ZHNkc0Bkc2RzZC5jb20=" } ["errors"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: The data and the code that you are showing here will _not_ cause that error. Please update your post with a working code snippet that reproduces your problem!

Answer (score -1):

> > > try to get_file_contents() function to fetch output data. or try
> > > json_decode(json_encode($array), true).

Comment: Dude, the array he shows us, just output from the php code,